# Registering an extension in Qt Designer with no associated widget plugin

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qtplugin

**TL;DR**

I want to register a Qt Designer extension but don't want any widget plugin, so any of the following can solve my problem:

- How do I create a plugin in Qt Designer that doesn't expose any widget in the widget box but that can register extensions?
- How do I register the extension without subclassing of `QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface`?

---

I'm working on a set of plugins for Qt Designer. These plugins expose custom widgets to the designer. All widgets (some dozens) inherit from a common class (`CCommonWidget`), such as:

```
CCommonWidget
|-> CLabel
|-> CPushButton
...
```

`CCommonWidget` define some common properties for all widgets. I'd like to expose them to Qt Designer through extensions (for example, the `QDesignerTaskMenuExtension`).

I started with a test in the `CLabel` plugin. Here the two relevant methods:

```
// Register the extensions in Qt Designer
void CLabelPlugin::initialize(QDesignerFormEditorInterface *formEditor)
{
    if (m_initialized) return;

    auto extensionManager = formEditor->extensionManager();
    Q_ASSERT(extensionManager);

    extensionManager->registerExtensions(new CLabelPluginFactory(extensionManager), Q_TYPEID(QDesignerTaskMenuExtension));

    m_initialized = true;
}

// The factory creates the menu extension if the widget is a CLabel
QObject* CLabelPluginFactory::createExtension(QObject *object, const QString &iid, QObject *parent) const
{
    if (iid != Q_TYPEID(QDesignerTaskMenuExtension)) return nullptr;

    if (auto label = dynamic_cast<CLabel*>(object))
        return new CLabelPluginMenu(label, parent);

    return nullptr;
}
```

It worked flawlessly and I was about to extend the idea to the rest of the plugins. Instead of copy/pasting the code I started with a `CCommonPlugin` and make every one to inherit from it. In order to make it as re-usable as possible I  changed the `createExtension` method to:

```
QObject* CCommonPluginFactory::createExtension(QObject *object, const QString &iid, QObject *parent) const
{
    if (iid != Q_TYPEID(QDesignerTaskMenuExtension)) return nullptr;

    if (auto label = dynamic_cast<CCommonWidget*>(object))
        return new CCommnPluginMenu(label, parent);

    return nullptr;
}
```

Here I realized that even if only on plugin (`CLabelPlugin`) was registering the extension factory, any other widget which inherits from `CCommonWidget` will show  the menu! (It was pretty obvious once I discovered it but before I just didn't think on it).

Now it was easier since I hadn't to change all the plugins (dozens) but just to create a new one, a *dummy common plugin*, that registers the extension factory.

The dummy plugin I've first created:

```
class CPluginCommon : public QObject, public QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES( QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface )

public:
    explicit CPluginCommon( QObject* parent=0 );

public: // QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface
    QWidget* createWidget( QWidget* parent ) { return nullptr; }
    QString group() const { return QString(); }
    QIcon icon() const { return QIcon(); }
    QString includeFile() const { return QString(); }
    bool isContainer() const { return false; }
    QString name() const { return QString(); }
    QString toolTip() const { return QString(); }
    QString whatsThis() const { return QString(); }

    virtual bool isInitialized() const override {
        return m_initialized;
    }
    virtual void initialize(QDesignerFormEditorInterface *formEditor) override;

private:
    bool m_initialized;
};
```

But a blank widget is displayed in the widget box of Qt Designer. I don't want an empty widget, I want *no widget*!

Another option is not to use these kind of plugins but I'm struggling to find a way to register the extension *without* a `QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface`, but all that I can find is to get the extensions manager within `QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface::initialize(QDesignerFormEditorInterface *formEditor)` (using `formEditor->extensionManager()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick answer**

To hide the widget from the widget box just return an empty XML (this is an undocumented feature):

```
class CPluginCommon : public QObject, public QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface {
// ...
public:
    QString domXml() const { return QString(); }
};
```

---

Reviewing the code of the plugins manager of Qt Designer, I found in the `QDesignerPluginManagerPrivate::addCustomWidget` method the following (`c` is a pointer to `QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface`)

```
const QString domXml = c->domXml();
if (!domXml.isEmpty()) { // Legacy: Empty XML means: Do not show up in widget box.
```

Given that, I saw that the default implementation of `domXml` does return a tiny XML fragment for a generic widget:

```
virtual QString domXml() const
{
    return QString::fromUtf8("<widget class=\"%1\" name=\"%2\"/>")
        .arg(name()).arg(name().toLower());
}
```

---

For completeness, as far as I have seen in the source code of the plugins manager of the Qt Designer, there is no way to load a plugin that doesn't inherits from `QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface`:

```
// Load plugins into widget database and factory.
void QDesignerIntegration::initializePlugins(QDesignerFormEditorInterface *formEditor)
{
    // load the plugins
    WidgetDataBase *widgetDataBase = qobject_cast<WidgetDataBase*>(formEditor->widgetDataBase());
    if (widgetDataBase) {
        widgetDataBase->loadPlugins();
    }

    if (WidgetFactory *widgetFactory = qobject_cast<WidgetFactory*>(formEditor->widgetFactory())) {
        widgetFactory->loadPlugins();
    }

    if (widgetDataBase) {
        widgetDataBase->grabDefaultPropertyValues();
    }
}
```

where

```
void WidgetDataBase::loadPlugins()
{
    // ...

    // 2) create a list plugins
    ItemList pluginList;
    const QDesignerPluginManager *pm = m_core->pluginManager();
    foreach(QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface* c, pm->registeredCustomWidgets())
        pluginList += createCustomWidgetItem(c, pm->customWidgetData(c));

    // ...
}

void WidgetFactory::loadPlugins()
{
    m_customFactory.clear();

    QDesignerPluginManager *pluginManager = m_core->pluginManager();

    QList<QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface*> lst = pluginManager->registeredCustomWidgets();
    foreach (QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface *c, lst) {
        m_customFactory.insert(c->name(), c);
    }
}
```